# Shopify: Which LIQUID file to look for to add a logo between product tabs section and related products section?

Tags: php, html, frontend, shopify, liquid

I need to place a an image/logo between the product tabs section and related products section in my Shopify store's product page. The screenshot below shows the location for the same. Could you please direct me to the file to do this? Our store is using Prestige theme.

[image]

Comment: need codes, buddy. no one can help you with a random image to a paid theme.   show your product.liquid or related-product.liquid or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an app for that.

If you need the same image on every product page, just add a section image using theme > customize > product page.

if you need a different image on each product, you can add a file product metafield (settings > metafileds > products) after that add the same section by the customize page but relate the section content to the metafield you just create, in this way you can select a different image by product.

You can even write a new section on code with extra options and the metafield, on this and create something very flexible.

Writing your code for use customize page and metafields is a good practice, it made your site more flexible and easy to use for nontechnical members of your team/client team.

Here more info about [metafields](https://shopify.dev/apps/metafields)

My response is more OS2.0, depending your theme will be easy or harder to accomplish.

If you're using an old theme that wasn't 2.0. It's better to change the theme to one more modern, if that is not an option, you can start [migrating the product template from liquid template to JSON template](https://shopify.dev/themes/migration)

Comment: Thanks again. My need is simple. The same credit-card image should appear on all product pages.

Comment: I don't seen an option to section image when I followed your instruction -> If you need the same image on every product page, just add a section image using theme > customize > product page.

Comment: I remember you from another question, you're using prestige theme, if you don't see sections when you open products page on customize means you are using an old version of prestige, you should visit https://themes.shopify.com/themes/prestige and update your theme to Prestige OS2.0

Comment: But our team doesn't want to update the theme for the time being. Is there another way to accomplish my requirement?

Comment: don't update is a bad idea... after that just add a new setting with type : image_picker on sections/product-template.liquid, and apply it where you need it on the section, with that you can fill the image easily by the customize page